# How to pass alias name to glm model formula in R

Tags: r, statistics, glm

I am building a Generalized Linear mixed model using the glmmLasso function in R. I pass the name of the categorical variable in the rnd argument of the function by hard coding the name of the variable, however, when i store the name of the variable in any other variable and pass the new variable name, it shows me an error.

```
re_model <- glmmLasso(formula, rnd = list(Geography =~1),
                       lambda=10000, data = input_data)
var = "Geography"
```

My data contains a variable Geography, if i hard code and write geography this works perfectly fine, but if i use the alias name var in the formula, it throws an error that undefined columns selected. Can someone help me with this please.

Comment: `rnd =  setNames(list(~1), var)`

Answer (score 0):

`Geography`is the name of a list element:

```
list(Geography =~1)
#$Geography
#~1
```

You can use `setNames` to set names programmatically:

```
var <- "Geography"
setNames(list(~1), var)
#$Geography
#~1
```

Comment: Alternatively create the list with `library(rlang) ; list2(!! var := ~1)`

Comment: Thank you so much. This works. I have an additional query, if for example i need to write rnd=list(Geography =~1 + Visits), where visits is another variable. How can i pass an alias for visits. For example, var= Geography, var1=visits and thus my formula should be like  rnd=list(var =~1 + var1). Any idea how this can be achieved. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: `visits <- "somevar"; reformulate(visits, intercept = TRUE)`

Comment: Sorry but not able to understand this clearly, can you please elaborate on this ?